# Random reals in Kamamori's "The Higher Infinite"

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm reading Kanamori's construction of the Solovay model, and had a question regarding random reals. We are forcing with the poset $\mathcal{B}^*$ of non-null Borel subsets of $\omega^\omega$, ordered by inclusion.

Kanamori writes:

> For any $n\in\omega$, 
>   $$
> \left\{C\in \mathcal{B}^*: C\text{ is closed } \wedge \exists k(C\subset \{f\in\omega^\omega: f(n)=k\})\right\} \tag{i}\label{(i)}
> $$
>   is dense in $\mathcal{B}^*$.
>
> Arguing in $V[G]$ there is a unique $x\in \omega^\omega$ specified by
>   $$ \{x\}=\bigcap\left\{ A^{V[G]}_c: c\in V\text{ is a closed code }\wedge A^V_c\in G\right\}$$
>   since this is an inersection of closed sets with the finite intersection property and (i) holds.

I think I see why the intersection is a singleton, namely, if there are two points there, we could separate them with a set as in (i).

That being said, I don't quite see why the intersection should be non-empty. Why is the finite intersection property relevant here, since we're not dealing with compact sets nor with sets of vanishing diameter?

Also, on a slightly unrelated note, I know one can talk about the ground model when working in the generic extension by adding a symbol $\check V$ to our forcing language. That being said, in this particular case, can we get away  without the definability of the ground model? What I have in mind is that we have a canonical name for $(\omega^\omega)^V$, and thus can say "$c\in V$ is a closed code" iff "$c\in \check{(\omega^\omega)}_G$ is a clode code"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A strengthening of $(i)$ is in fact true: for each $n$, the set of codes for positive-measure closed sets contained in some $$\{f\in\omega^\omega: \sigma\prec f\}$$ for some $\sigma\in\omega^n$ is dense in $\mathcal{B}^*$. This means that we effectively *are* forcing with closed sets of vanishing diameter.

- Note that this is actually a consequence of $(i)$ as written - this is exactly what the "$k$" business gets us (it says that densely we stabilize on each individual bit, which yields dense stabilization of finite prefixes). But I think the phrasing above makes it clearer what's going on.

In fact, here's an explicit definition of the unique real in question: it's the real $r\in V[G]$ such that for each $n\in\omega$ there is some $X\in G$ such that $$V[G]\models X\subseteq\{f\in\omega^\omega: r\upharpoonright n\prec f\}.$$  *(Incidentally, if we let $A_\sigma=\{f\in\omega^\omega: \sigma\prec f\}$ we have $(A_\sigma)^{V[G]}\cap V=(A_\sigma)^V$, and even though $r\not\in V$ we have $r\upharpoonright n\in V$ for each $n\in\omega$, so we can basically juggle between models at will in this context.)*

---

As to definability, we don't need definability of the ground model (although [we have it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83203/definability-of-ground-model)) to lift codes for closed sets from $V$ to $V[G]$. Specifically, the set of codes for closed sets is appropriately absolute: if $c\in V$ is a code for a closed set in the sense of $V$, then $c$ is also a code for a closed set in the sense of $V[G]$. (A code for a closed set is really just a subtree of $\omega^{<\omega}$, after all, and its interpretation is the set of paths through the tree.) Moreover, basic properties of closed sets are also appropriately absolute: if, in $V$, $f$ is a real in the closed set coded by $c$, then $f$ is also a real in the closed set coded by $c$ in $V[G]$. (Because being a path through a tree is absolute.)

*(In fact, the "atomic" absoluteness mentioned above isn't limited to closed sets: by Shoenfield absoluteness, for any $\Pi^1_2$ code $p$ we have $Set(p)^{V[G]}\cap V=Set(p)^V$. It's only at higher complexity levels that this breaks down. Of course, more nuanced statements break down earlier - for example, closed codes don't switch from empty to non-empty or vice versa, but since being constructible is a $\Sigma^1_2$ property we know that $\Pi^1_2$ codes can.)*

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks! Just to clarify, what did you mean when you said "there is some $c\in G$"? $G$ is a $\mathcal{B}^\ast$-generic filter, so its elements should be Borel sets of reals, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Reveillark I was thinking of it as a set of Borel codes rather than actual Borel sets, but you're right, that's not what it is (although we can approach it that way).

Comment: Ah, I see, working directly with the codes makes sense. Thanks again :D